# Error in runserver with Django on windows 10

Tags: django, windows-10, otree

I am using python 3.5 and windows 10, but had the same issue using windows 8, and that is the traceback i get while trying to runserver:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\noabendor87\documents\otree\manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv, script_file=**file**)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\otree\management\cli.py", line
>   177, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__
>   .py", line 346, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py"
>   , line 394, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands
>   \runserver.py", line 49, in execute
>       super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py"
>   , line 445, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands
>   \runserver.py", line 88, in handle
>       self.run(**options)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands
>   \runserver.py", line 97, in run
>       autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", li
>   ne 336, in main
>       reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", li
>   ne 307, in python_reloader
>       exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
>     File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", li
>   ne 293, in restart_with_reloader
>       exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character

I have already tried following the instructions in the following link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714826/error-in-manage-py-runserver-with-django-on-windows-8-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLtuv.jpg)

but it did not help.

This is how the lines of code look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLtuv.jpg)

(Since Im a new user I cannot paste the image to the original post)

Anyone have encountered something similar and have a solution?

Comment: Don't use images for showing code. Post your actual code.

Comment: And format the code properly using backticks.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have similar problems because of the difficulties with the virtual environment in windows 10. Try running the powershell as an administrator and do "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" or "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" if remotesigned does not work. Do this before activating the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

first I will like you check the django version you are working with my "type python -m django --version" or "pip freeze". check weather its compatible with the python version on your pc. if it's not install compatible python version. then check weather  "**init**.py" is within your project directory, if not add it to your project directory. then run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted" on your terminal. then run activate your virtualenv, then run "python manage.py runserver"