# Error in runserver with Django 1.8.8 on windows 10

Tags: python, django, windows-10

I am using python 3.5 and windows 10, but had the same issue using windows 8, and that is the traceback i get while trying to runserver:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\noabendor87\documents\otree\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv, script_file=__file__)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\otree\management\cli.py", line
177, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 346, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 49, in execute
super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 445, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 88, in handle
self.run(**options)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 97, in run
autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 336, in main
reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in python_reloader
exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
File "c:\users\noabendor87\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 293, in restart_with_reloader
exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
```

The code is

```
286>def restart_with_reloader():
287>while True:
288>    args = [sys.executable] + ['-W%s' % o for o in sys.warnoptions] + sys.argv
289>    if sys.platform == "win32":
290>        args = ['"%s"' % arg for arg in args]
291>    new_environ = os.environ.copy()
292>    new_environ["RUN_MAIN"] = 'true'
293>    exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
294>    if exit_code != 3:
295>        return exit_code
```

I have tried doing all that is mentioned in the following link:
[Error in manage.py runserver with Django on windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714826/error-in-manage-py-runserver-with-django-on-windows-8-1)

but the solutions offered there did not solve the problem.

Anyone can share some insights?

Comment: You shared the traceback but apparently not the actual error. Can you please share the error you're running into?

Comment: that's not a bad idea......
and that is the error i get:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character